# How to debug xcode project in qt?

Tags: c++, xcode, qt, debugging, qml

I want to embed some UI written using Qt and QML via QMacNativeWidget.
And I want to debug QML using Qt Creator, cause I can't debug QML with XCode. Do you know if it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can** debug Qt/QML in Xcode since it's essentially just a regular C/C++ project. The only thing you need is a proper Xcode project (`.xcodeproj`).

You could use [CMake](https://cmake.org) for project configuration/generation instead of relying on QtCreator's `.pro` format. With CMake you could switch between IDEs (project generators is the better term) on demand and try things out when it gets OS specific.

If that's not an option (there might be several reasons), you still can generate an Xcode project from an existing `.pro` solution via [qmake](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-manual.html) in the command line:

`qmake -spec macx-xcode project.pro`

This can be found in the [Qt for macOS](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/osx.html) section of the docs.

Comment: QML is a modified JavaScript, but not C++. So I probably can't debug it from XCode.

Comment: Yes. It helps, I can open the project from both qt creator and XCode